# Searching for a substring in a key of a key-value pair more efficient when stored in a data structure or in a long string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-structures, key-value

I have a string searching problem and two ideas came to mind on how to implement it. I was wondering if people can indicate which method would give me more efficient performance, or perhaps even suggest a better way of doing it?

The problem is I have a text file of around 450kb containing data in the following format:

```
description1, code1\n
description2, code2\n
description3, code3\n
...
```

It is two columns of data delimited by a comma and each record consists of a *description* and a *code*.

The *code* is a short three character text that is not immediately meaningful to the user, which is why there is description data paired with the code.

The *description* data is a short sentence that describes to the user what the *code* means.

I'm trying to create a GUI where the user can enter a search keyword in an editable text field which is then used to search against the description data. The system would then return back all the filtered records, i.e., all the description data that has the keyword as a substring and the code that it is paired with for the user to select. This occurs for each character the user types.

The first idea that came to mind on how to implement this feature is to create a key-value pair collection using the description data as key, such as a `NameValueCollection`, and then use a foreach loop to go through each record and search the key for the matching substring.

The second idea is to read the whole text file into one long string, and use the `String.IndexOf()` method to search for the keyword and wherever there is a hit in the search, I extract that portion of the record to return to the user.

The second idea came to mind because I was concerned by the performance impact that the first idea may have. I've read that the `IndexOf` method in use with `StringComparison.Ordinal` performs better than a Boyer–Moore string search algorithm so I think implementing it this way would have better performance?

So when searching for a substring in the key, does it provide faster retrieval to store the whole file as a string or in a NameValueCollection, or are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: 450k is crazy small.  you don't need anything fancy.  the naive bruteforce thing will work in a blink of an eye.

Comment: Really? I was thinking that I need something really fast since the user is initiating a search through all the records for each character that is typed down. Maybe I'll test this out first before going off in the fancy direction.

Comment: time grep foo /usr/share/dict/words takes .041s on my machine, and that is reading a 910kb file.  Your search won't be as fast as grep, but you'll have the data in memory already.  human reaction time is around .25s

Comment: @rrenaud: Even though if humans cannot react to things faster than 250ms, their ability to detect events as simultaneous or separate is much finer.  While having screen updates deferred until a half-second after the last keystroke may be less visually distracting than updating after every keystroke, even 100ms of lag is enough to make something perceptibly "non-instantaneous".

Answer (score 2):

If you have a wide collection of strings that you are planning on searching for the exact same substring, you have many options available.

One option would be to use the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) to search for the search query in every single one of the lines of the file.  The total runtime of doing this will be O(m + n + z), where m is the length of the query, z is the number of total matches, and n is the total number of characters in all of the strings in the file.

A better but more complex option would be to build a [generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#Generalized_suffix_tree) out of all the lines of the file.  You could then find all matching lines in time O(n + z), where n is the length of the pattern to search for and z is the total number of lines in the file.  This requires O(m) preprocessing time, where m is the total number of characters in the file.  This is much, much faster than the first option, but you would probably have to find a good suffix tree library, as suffix tree construction algorithms are fairly complex.

Hope this helps!